# Language and Region

Tags: language

I am trying to set the language of my Lenovo laptop to English while keeping my region and Formats set in German. It seems I can only keep the language set with the region of the native speaking country if that makes any sense, anyone know any ways around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same setup you're looking for. This can be changed in the System Settings app.

All Settings > Personal > Language & Region.

- Language: English
- Region: United States
- Formats: Germany

[image: My Settings]

This way I can have English language applications, a dvorak alternate keyboard layout and German date formats. Day of the week and month names are still German. To change that you'll need dconf-editor and you'll need to do some experimentation in system/locale.

Comment: Good Day Patrick,

thanks for the reply.

Ill try this set, i am not too comfortable to tinker with dconf files yet but ill most likely keep the set you mention

kind regards

Comment: Bitteschön. If you don't want to get into dconf, then these settings are as close as you can get to what you described. Cheers.